# How to turn off/mute the USSD notification sound in Jelly Bean?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, audio, ussd

I recently got my Lava Iris 501's OS updated to 4.1.1 and now it even chimes whenever my operator sends me a 'Last Call/SMS/Data Cost' notification. This happens even on the Silent/Meeting modes also.

What can I do so that my phone doesn't bug me at my workplace?